# How to async load image in Jetpack compose without third party libraries

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have questions about loading images from url. How to async load image in Jetpack Compose? I know coin library and use it is pretty simple and works great. But libraries like coil, glide, picasso are prohibited, only Android SDK and Google supported are allowed.

Thank you for your advices

Something like this? But how to display in Jetpack Compose UI?

```
@Composable
fun LoadImage(url: String, @DrawableRes placeHolderImage: Int): MutableState<Bitmap?> {
    var bitmapState: MutableState<Bitmap?> = mutableStateOf(null)

    //show place holder image
    val defaultBitmap =
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(LocalContext.current.resources, placeHolderImage)
    bitmapState.value = defaultBitmap

    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val urlConnection = URL(url).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        try {
            urlConnection.doInput = true
            urlConnection.connect()
            val input = BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.inputStream)
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                bitmapState.value = bitmap
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {

        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect()
        }
    }
    return bitmapState
}
```

Comment: "But libraries like coil, glide, picasso are prohibited" - why are they prohibited?  The official documentation recoomends you use them .. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/images/loading#internet-loading

Comment: You cannot write a Compose UI app, as you are not allowed to use Kotlin. Kotlin includes a library (e.g., `com.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7`), and "only Android SDK and Google suported are allowed".

Comment: I think the OP probably means "no third-party libraries", and Kotlin would be allowed as it's officially recommended and integrated into first-party stuff like Compose. But by that standard, so would third-party image libraries, which are recommended for handling images in general (https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap?hl=en) over rolling your own solution. Third-party libraries are maintained so you don't have to, you can just stick to a specific version if you like, they tend to come with permissive licences (always check) and it saves you time and headaches

Comment: If you actually want to write this yourself, it's like any other async network operation, except you need to handle things like decoding, caching, potential memory issues, resizing to the appropriate size for the containing view, passing the bitmap back to the UI thread for display, cancellation (for things like `RecyclerView`s) etc. It's a lot of work with a lot of potential issues to handle, so you're probably not going to get a code example, and everyone's going to recommend a library that's already been developed to do all this for you. Maybe talk to whoever put the restriction on you?

Comment: To be honest I don’t know why the libraries are prohibited. It is part of job interview task. Task assignment is async load image and cache it.

Comment: My recommendation is to not accept the job. That being said... you could use `HttpUrlConnection` to download the image to a file (perhaps in `getCacheDir()` on `Context`). Then, use `BitmapFactory` to load the image into a `Bitmap`, and use `asImageBitmap()` to get an `ImageBitmap` to show in an `Image()` composable.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you but when I have function which return bitmap after async done. How to display it in jetpack compose UI?

Comment: As I noted earlier, there is [an `asImageBitmap()` extension function on `Bitmap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/package-summary#(android.graphics.Bitmap).asImageBitmap()) that you can use to get an `ImageBitmap`.

Comment: You can use that with [this version of the `Image()` composable](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary#Image(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ImageBitmap,kotlin.String,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment,androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale,kotlin.Float,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ColorFilter,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.FilterQuality)).